# Calling a method that returns a value each time or store it in a variable in PHP and MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, methods, view, model

In general, we pass a model through the controller to the view when we work with MVC. In case the model has a method that returns a certain value which will be needed several times on the same view. Which is a better practice between calling that method each time we need it's returned value or call it once and store the returned value in a variable and use that variable each time we need it? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's better to call that method once and store it into a variable. Imagine that this method contains a complex calculation, an API call or something like that. In this cases it would be much faster to calculate/execute it once and to store it in a variable.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to know. How about when you keep declaring a new variable for each method call and you have many methods that you need to call on one view. Does it affect the memory when there are many variables declared? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You mean declare a new variable for each method call of the *same* method? Is it possible in your case to override a single variable with the method calls? 
Of course, if you have multiple variables with the result of the same call, this needs more memory than a single variable.

Comment: I mean you have several methods that you need to call on the same view and from each method you need its returned value several times. If you declare a new variable for each method, you will have several variables. and more variables cost more memory. Here we need to make decision. I am not sure what is a better decision but I think declare a new variable for each method and use that variable is a better decision.

Comment: Ah, I understand. In this case, you have to decide between code readability and *performance*. I don't think that the used memory for a variable is so high that you would notice it (how big is the result of your methods?), so i would also use one variable per method, but with one call for each method while the result is stored in a variable instead of calling the method multiple times.